# How to manually show Windows 8 Metro loading wheel / loading dots using Javascript

Tags: javascript, microsoft-metro, winjs

When using a datasource on ListViews or similar the Windows 8 loading wheel appears. This is fine, but I still want to start and stop this loading wheel manually in a container of my choice. I'd also like to know how to use the loading dots. How could I go about to achieve this?

[image: Windows 8 Metro Loading Wheel]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Jevar's suggestion I managed to find a [Quickstart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465487.aspx) guide for adding progress controls. What I wanted was indeed a ProgressRing, more spesifically a indeterminate progress ring. Here is how it is done in HTML/JS

**HTML**:

```
<label class="progressRingText">
    <progress class="win-ring withText"></progress>Processing</label>
```

**CSS**

```
progress.withText
{
    color: inherit; /* Uses the same text color as the page */
    vertical-align: text-bottom; /* Makes the bottom of the control align with the bottom of its label */
}

/* Text style for a label for the progress ring */
.progressRingText
{
    font-family: "Segoe UI";
}

/* Text style for a label for a default size progress ring */
.progressRingText
{
    font-size: 11pt;
    line-height: 15pt;
}

/* The margin to separate the ring and its label */
.progressRingText progress
{
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use the same width and height for the

> progress

For example

```
<progress style="width:50px;height:50px;">
```

element, you will get that effect.